# Got "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." with ngix reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, selenoid

I have nginx reverse proxy

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name $APP_DOMAIN;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html @backend @frontend @selenoid;

  location /seltest/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    rewrite  ^/seltest/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://selenoid_application_server/;
  }
...
```

when I go to /seltest I got You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Comment: This is not related to Selenoid. You really need to enable Javascript in browser.

Comment: seems I found problem, selenoid is loaded on my.domain/seltest but in it code there is <script src="/static/js/file.js"> so it try to access my.domain/static/js/file.js, but file is placed in my.domain/seltest/static.js.file.js is there any soolution for this?

Comment: https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-ui/issues/49